# Php Text game trying to make outcome based on percentage

Tags: php, sql, game-engine

This has ben really hard for me I have been working on this for 3 days and am about to give up lol... :(

I'm trying to code a feature in my game that the outcome is successful based on a percentage,
and this percentage needs to go up the more you use the feature. You start low at 1% and would goto jail most of the time, or just fail the feature. But as u do it more at hit 100% you would be successful every time here is the code I got so far. If anyone knows the correct way to code this and point me in the right direction it would be very helpful I'm pretty sure I have to recode most of this. if crime chance hits 100 this way itll always be 1 so u will always be succeful but there must be a better way to do this with percents.

crimechance1 is set to default 1 so it starts as 1 and goes up each time u do the function
at 100 u will always complete the function..  i need this to work at percents though example at 60 u have 60% chance of passing   at 80 u have 80% chance of passing.

code updated

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['Commit']){

$radiobutton=$_POST['radiobutton'];

if ($radiobutton == "1"){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$crimechance1 = htmlspecialchars($row->crime1);

    $crime_chance = 100 / $crimechance1;
    $crimechance1++;

if ($crime_chance == 1){
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET exp='100' WHERE name='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "You passed the Function";
}
else {
echo "You failed the Function";
}

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show an example with numbers what's the input and what is the current output vs. expected output ?

Comment: like if u start with 24 of crime chance, you only get it when the random hits #1, i need some way to do it of percentage 1-100. u start with 1% chance of winning, and later u have 100% chance of winning

Comment: You have many variables in your code: crime1a, crime1, crimechance1, exp, Crime_exp and many other variables which their name is not self explanatory. If you want other people to understand your code (and help you) you should use better names or even better, add code-comments.

Comment: crime1 and crime1a are used for the wait time before u can use the function again, crime exp is a reward for the function crime money is another reward for the function name is the users name crimetime is used to calculate the wait between using functions.

Comment: i just relized i had this harder then it needs to look so i recoded it and made it simple we can work on getting this work then i can just add the rest later

Answer (score 0):

This outcome i found last night is working much better, please answer if you think you have a better one

```
$perc = 40;
$rand  = rand(1, 100);
if ($rand <= $perc) {
    //pass
} else {
   //Fail
}
```